# Processing image to display

Tags: javascript, html

I want to check for the size of image, and then display the image as a cropped version by defining the set size(w*h).

How can i do this?

This is the code I have tried:

```
 var filesSelected = document.getElementById("inputFileToLoad").files;
    if (filesSelected.length > 0)
    {
        var fileToLoad = filesSelected[0];

        if (fileToLoad.type.match("image.*"))
        {
            var fileReader = new FileReader();
            fileReader.onload = function(fileLoadedEvent)
            {
                var imageLoaded = document.createElement("img");
                imageLoaded.src = fileLoadedEvent.target.result;
                document.body.appendChild(imageLoaded);
            };
            fileReader.readAsDataURL(fileToLoad);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="file" onchange="handleFiles(this.files[0])" id="inputFileToLoad">
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>

function handleFiles(fileToLoad) {
if (fileToLoad.type.match("image.*")) {
    var fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.onload = function (fileLoadedEvent) {
        var img = new Image();
        img.onload = function () {
            var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");

            canvas.width = img.width;
            canvas.height = img.height;

            var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

            ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

            // cropped = ctx.getImageData(x, y, crop_width, crop_height);
            cropped = ctx.getImageData(500, 500, 200, 200);

            // clearing is optional ... new img is over the old one
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

            // re-size canvas to croped img size
            canvas.width = 200;
            canvas.height = 200;

            ctx.putImageData(cropped, 0, 0)
        };


        img.src = fileLoadedEvent.target.result;
    };
    fileReader.readAsDataURL(fileToLoad);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

1. draw the imageLoaded into canvas of the size w*h shifted by some position
2. get the image data by `yourcanvas.toDataUrl()`
3. place the image data into image element

The function that does this

```
function getImagePortion(imgObj, newWidth, newHeight, startX, startY, ratio){
 /* the parameters: - the image element - the new width - the new height - the x point we start taking pixels - the y point we start taking pixels - the ratio */
 //set up canvas for thumbnail
 var tnCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
 var tnCanvasContext = canvas.getContext('2d');
 tnCanvas.width = newWidth; tnCanvas.height = newHeight;

 /* use the sourceCanvas to duplicate the entire image. This step was crucial for iOS4 and under devices. Follow the link at the end of this post to see what happens when you don’t do this */
 var bufferCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
 var bufferContext = bufferCanvas.getContext('2d');
 bufferCanvas.width = imgObj.width;
 bufferCanvas.height = imgObj.height;
 bufferContext.drawImage(imgObj, 0, 0);

 /* now we use the drawImage method to take the pixels from our bufferCanvas and draw them into our thumbnail canvas */
 tnCanvasContext.drawImage(bufferCanvas, startX,startY,newWidth * ratio, newHeight * ratio,0,0,newWidth,newHeight);
 return tnCanvas.toDataURL();
}
```

is step by step described [here](https://yellowpencil.com/blog/cropping-images-with-javascript/)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys,
Using Canvas is the right approach here. This is my final piece of code
Here is the final Code:

Ref [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/influenztial/qy7h5/)

```
<html>
<title>
    Upload Image
</title>
<div style="text-align: center">
    <h1>: UPLOAD IMAGE : </h1>
</div>

<div>
    <input type="file" id="imageLoader" name="imageLoader" onchange="checkFileDetails()"/>
    <br/>
    <h3>Horizontal<h3>
    <canvas id="imageCanvas1"></canvas> 
    <br/>
    <h3>Vertical<h3>
    <canvas id="imageCanvas2"></canvas>
    <br/>
    <h3>Horizontal Small<h3>
    <canvas id="imageCanvas3"></canvas>
    <br/>
    <h3>Gallery<h3>
    <canvas id="imageCanvas4"></canvas>
</div>
<script>
    //Check for the image Size and type




    // Display Image in the required format

    var imageLoader = document.getElementById('imageLoader');
    imageLoader.addEventListener('change', handleImage1, false);
    var canvas1 = document.getElementById('imageCanvas1');
    var ctx1 = canvas1.getContext('2d');

    function handleImage1(e){
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(event){
            var img = new Image();
            img.onload = function(){
                canvas1.width = 755;
                canvas1.height = 450;
                ctx1.drawImage(img,0,0);
            }
            img.src = event.target.result;
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
    }

    var imageLoader1 = document.getElementById('imageLoader');
    imageLoader1.addEventListener('change', handleImage2, false);
    var canvas2 = document.getElementById('imageCanvas2');
    var ctx2 = canvas2.getContext('2d');

    function handleImage2(e){
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(event){
            var img = new Image();
            img.onload = function(){
                canvas2.width = 365;
                canvas2.height = 450;
                ctx2.drawImage(img,0,0);
            }
            img.src = event.target.result;
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
    }

    var imageLoader2 = document.getElementById('imageLoader');
    imageLoader2.addEventListener('change', handleImage3, false);
    var canvas3 = document.getElementById('imageCanvas3');
    var ctx3 = canvas3.getContext('2d');

    function handleImage3(e){
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(event){
            var img = new Image();
            img.onload = function(){
                canvas3.width = 365;
                canvas3.height = 212;
                ctx3.drawImage(img,0,0);
            }
            img.src = event.target.result;
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
    }

    var imageLoader3 = document.getElementById('imageLoader');
    imageLoader3.addEventListener('change', handleImage4, false);
    var canvas4 = document.getElementById('imageCanvas4');
    var ctx4 = canvas4.getContext('2d');

    function handleImage4(e){
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(event){
            var img = new Image();
            img.onload = function(){
                canvas4.width = 380;
                canvas4.height = 380;
                ctx4.drawImage(img,0,0);
            }
            img.src = event.target.result;
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
    }


</script>
```